# Casting a pointer to uint64_t

Tags: c++, casting

For a `const char *p`, is it guaranteed that `(uint64_t)(uintptr_t)p` has the same value as `(uint64_t)p`, assuming both options compile?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.  Why close as unclear?

Comment: @L.F. - it's standard operating procedure for the some of the C++ crew at SO to vote to close any questions they don't like, which have a smell of bad design or some other "forbidden practice". The exact close reason isn't really material to them. Admittedly I did have some typos that made it less clear than it could have been, but RL fixed them up.

Answer (score 4):

It would be entirely legitimate (and even reasonable) for a compiler whose target used e.g. 48-bit pointers consisting of a 16-bit segment and 32-bit offset (segmented-model 80386 works that way) to handle conversions to `uint64_t` by storing the 16-bit segment and 32-bit offset to the destination object, leaving the remaining 16 bits holding whatever they happened to hold previously, provided that a conversion from `uint64_t` back to a pointer ignored the bits in question.  It would also be reasonable for such a platform to define `uintptr_t` as synonymous with `uint64_t`, and treat conversions to `uint64_t` the same way.

All that is guaranteed about conversions is that `(void*)p==(void*)(uintptr_t)p`.  There isn't guarantee that `(uintptr_t)p == (uintptr_t)p`, nor even that a pointer produced through a round-trip cast can be meaningfully dereferenced in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that `(uintptr_t)p == (uintptr_t)p` wasn't guaranteed. I guess that means "all bets off".

Comment: @BeeOnRope: I really wish the authors of the Standard would officially recognize various behavioral guarantees that quality implementations should support when practical, and provide macros, intrinsics, or other such means by which strictly conforming programs could indicate what guarantees they require, and refuse to compile on implementations that don't promise to uphold them.  Most platforms could at no cost guarantee that `(uintptr_t)p` and `(uintptr_t)q` will have the same ordering and equality relationships as `p` and `q`. and would be useful on platforms that can uphold it.

Comment: On the other hand, if you need this, your design is broken.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How did you become all-knowing as to what programmers need to do?

Comment: @supercat Never. I'm all-knowing as to what they _should_ do. Subtle difference!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How would you suggest that a programmer e.g. check whether a pointer identifies an address within a particular block of memory?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - um, what? Using the value of a pointer, e.g., as input to a hash function is a totally reasonable practice.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: On most platforms it would be.  It's possible to imagine a platform that uses "fat pointers" that contain information about how they were derived, and whose bit patterns might not work with conventional hash functions.  On the other hand, the fact that a technique might not work with 0.01% of platforms should not imply that one shouldn't be used on the other 99+%.

Comment: @supercat - sure, although in this case I'm using a pointer hash and comparison as a quick best-effort check: if the pointers match, we can be sure the objects are the same. If they don't match, they may _still_ be the same due to the weird 0.01%, or simply because you have two distinct objects with the same value: so in any case there is a second lookup based on the object _value_ which will also catch the 0.01% case. So the only assumption I am making is that if pointers converted to `uintptr` compare equal, they are equal.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: How would such a hash function work on e.g. an 80386 compiler where a pointer-to-`uintptr_t` cast yields meaningless data in the upper 16 bits?

Comment: Well if by luck the upper bits were the same (say consistently zero), the hash would work and you'd find the earlier inserted identical pointer if it existed. OTOH if the upper bits differed for otherwise identical pointers, you'd fail to find the identical pointer during this initial pointer-based lookup, but then as described fall back to a lookup and hash based on the string contents which doesn't involve the pointer at all and hence doesn't care about 386 weirdness.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Most useful hash-table algorithms require the ability to assume with 100% certainty that items with different hashes don't need to be compared.  While one could perhaps get some benefit from a hash table that starts by looking first in a bucket with the right hash, but then scans every bucket if no match is found, most practical uses of hash tables would require the ability to assume that if no hash is found, the object simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @supercat - I understand how straightforward hash tables work. As I've described above, in my use case, same object with different hash works fine because there is a second lookup that will find the object anyways (this is needed not just because of the `uintptr_t` weirdness, but because comparing addresses will always have false negatives anyways because two objects might have identical values but different addresses). If it helps, you can think of it as a "cache" built into the hash table.

Comment: Another use of this cast to store pointer values in a Java object using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

That is only true if the range of numbers representable by `uintptr_t` are all representable by `uint64_t`.  As a practical matter, that will be true on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, but not, for example, 128-bit platforms should they exist.

You really shouldn't rely on this, and just stick with `uintptr_t` where you need pointers as integers.

Comment: Even when using `uintptr_t`, there would be no guarantee that `(uintptr_t)p == (uintptr_t)p`.

Comment: Note that in both cases the result is `uint64_t` so it isn't clear to me what the problem on 128-bit platforms would be (I'm not asking about `(uintptr_t)p` vs `(uint64_t)p`).

Comment: @supercat I doubt that. Both expressions must regain their original value when cast back to their original pointer type, and that would be impossible if that expression were false.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If pointers had 64 significant bits, that would be true, but if pointers have 48 bits while `uintptr_t` has 64, and a cast from `uintptr_t` to a pointer ignores 16 bits, then those 16 bits could be populated arbitrarily when casting from a pointer to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @supercat Okay, yeah, that's true.